# ASP.NET, VisualStudio 2010: Web.config not publishing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config

For some mysterious reason, all of a sudden when I publish my website, Web.config does not get coppied over.

At first when I saw that the properties of Web.config was set to "Do not copy", that seemed like the reason... but when I change the option, it doesn't stick.

Is there some shortcut key or some global TFS setting that might effect this?

This has never happened before...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently, if you look at "Properties", there is an option called "Build Action" ... set this to "Content" if you would like this file to be coppied over on Publish. If not, select "None"

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/p/1528920/3698633.aspx

Comment: This is something that happens when you add a new web.config file.

Answer (score -1):

In Solution Explorer> Right click on Web.config file > Properties.

In the Properties dialog box,

set Build Action = Content

set Copy to Output Directory = Copy always

[image]

Comment: "set Copy to Output Directory = Copy always"  
This copied the web.config to your *bin* folder, which you do NOT want.